# R matrix and data.frame mix-up

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame in R with columns that also have column names.
I have another data.frame with 0s and -1s that controls which columns to use from the first data.frame in a subsequent analysis.
I now ran into an issue that I cannot wrap my head around.

First of all, the "offending" line of code is:

```
covar.data<-covar.data[,!onoff]
```

FYI I have confirmed both `covar.data` and `onoff` are data.frames.

When I run this with `onoff` selecting 2 or more columns, everything is fine, and the resulting `covar.data` is still a data.frame - and this is important, because I need to use the column names in the rest of my analysis.

However, if I have `onoff` selecting only 1 column, `covar.data` turns into a matrix!! This is a problem, because the column name also disappears!
I tried

```
covar.data<-as.data.frame(covar.data[,!onoff])
```

and

```
covar.data<-as.data.frame(covar.data[,!onoff], col.names=TRUE)
```

but that didn't make a difference in the disappearance of the column name.

I don't understand why R decides to turn the data.frame into a matrix (only for the times I am left with one column), and I cannot figure out how to preserve the data.frame PLUS the column names.

Comment: I don't think it's turning into a matrix, it's probably turning into a vector. Try `covar.data[,!onoff, drop=F]`. And are you sure `onoff` is a data.frame? How exactly are you indexing data.frame columns with another data.frame? That doesn't make sense. Perhaps you should `dput` the objects or at least give the results of `str` so we can reproduce.

Comment: @MrFlick can you post this as a solution, because drop=F works. I must add though that R really turns it into a matrix: I tested is.matrix(covar.data), is.data.frame(covar.data) and is.vector(covar.data) for situations where I selected 1 column, and situations where I selected 2 or more columns. And I also tested that onoff is a data.frame, same method.

Comment: See also http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/design-flaws-in-r-2

Comment: I am really confused as to what exactly you have in onoff. Is your data like this?? `covar.data<-data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3); onoff<-data.frame(a=1,b=-1,c=1); covar.data[, !onoff]`

Comment: `onoff<-data.frame(a=0,b=-1,c=0` The columns with 0 are preserved from covar.data after doing `covar.data[,!onoff]`

Comment: That is one of the more unusual ways i've never seen to subset a `data.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select a single column of a `data.frame`, R assumes you want to extract that data as a vector rather than returning another data.frame (and in most cases this is exactly the behavior you want). But if you do want to keep that single column as a `data.frame`, then you should do

```
covar.data[,!onoff, drop=F]
```